# Drop a notice in the Inbox when a mod edits a user's post

Tags: feature-request, edits, moderation, global-inbox

Mods have two supersecret ways that they can notify a user that they're doing it wrong.  First way is to contact the user privately (used for "serious bidnez") and the second way is by leaving a comment before deleting a post.  I'd like to suggest a third way.

*When, in the course of moderation events,* a moderator must edit a post, I suggest the moderator have the option for the user to be notified in their **inbox** that [such an edit was made](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/107443/revisions), the message presented being the edit summary.  The message should link to the revision history of the post, so that the user can see what was changed.

Eamples of usage would be:

- Every time you preface your title with tags I kill a kitten.  Please, think of the kittens.
- I removed all the subjective content of your question.  I also think you're ugly.
- TAG LINE!  Slowly I turned... Step, by step... Inch, by inch...
- Please don't link to spammy websites.  It makes you look like a spammy spammer.
- Your post lacked narwhal.  I fixed it.

[image]

Comment: You want to spam a user's inbox every time a mod edits their post for any reason? That seems bad

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: How many times do you edit a single user's posts?  And spam?  Moderators don't spam.

Comment: @Wont 733 times so far on UL. Maybe it's not insane if "in the course of moderation events" means something, but I don't know what that is -- it only signals them if you edit a flagged post?

Comment: Isn't that what the `Reponse`-Tab in the userprofile is for?

Comment: I'm in two minds on this. I can see cases where it would be useful - but I think it should be optional so if I'm just fixing spellings/formatting/grammar I can do so like any other user.

Comment: If it's optional then that's fine, but I don't know why mod edits are somehow special, as though regular users don't clean up posts constantly. We could add a "you've been bad!" message every time a user's post gets edited, but that would get ridiculous

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: K, I see what you mean.  You may edit a post but not think it worthwhile to notify the user something was changed that doesn't indicate the user is unfamiliar about how StackOverflow works.  I've edited to include the optional part.  Also, I want to stress that this would be an option for mods only, as a means of communicating to a user that their post contained something that we don't allow.

Comment: @PaddedCell: you don't get notified that something has been added.  I know that I don't check that tab ever; I only respond to the notification at the top or items in my inbox.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ If a moderator thinks the user needs to be notified, why not leave a comment on the post and be done with it?

Comment: Well, sometimes you don't want to leave a comment as it adds noise and unneeded discussion out in the open.  Currently, if you want to accomplish this, you have to edit, give a reason, then comment.  This would combine the tasks, and the link to the revision history emphasizes the changes made.  Also, I'm lazy.

Comment: Is the idea that contacting a user privately is used only for "serious bidnez" codified anywhere, or is just convention? Is there any reason that mechanism can't be used for *all* 'in the course of moderation' mod-to-user communication?

Comment: @AakashM It says so in the mod tool, and they're pretty strict about it

Comment: @AakashM: It is stressed in the UI that contacting a user directly should only be done "to address **serious** behavior problems".  Mod messages are pretty intrusive, so the more there are the more you get bugged (we get notified by annoying popdown bar every time one is sent).  Also, there are quite a few, and the UI doesn't handle it well at the moment, so if everyone was contacting users over trivial stuff we might loose track of the important messages.

Comment: I thought you already get notified when _anyone_ (not juts a moderator) edits your posts.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn It shows up in the responses tab, but it doesn't generate a notification.

Comment: Well my suggestion would be to extend the mod-message functionality to include a less intrusive (ie inbox-landing) channel, rather than requiring such a message to be tied to an edit.

Comment: @AakashM: I'm for that as well.  I just like the idea of rubbing their nose in the pile of poo and going, "No!  No tags in title!  Bad user!  Bad!".  Less offensively, it helps educate and to reinforce that education about what is and what is not acceptable here.

Answer (score 5):

I would just

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

the edit summary you entered for the edit (you *did* enter a valid edit summary explaining the edit, right? *right?*) into a **comment on the post.**

While I think it's sufficient for such things to live in the edit comments on `/revisions` it can also be sensible to hoist them out of the revisions page and place them in a comment where every reader can benefit from your edumifcation of the masses.